# Joint with three degrees of freedom URDF

Tags: ros, joint, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently trying to attach a caster to my robot. Therefore I need a continuous joint with three degrees of freedom.
This is my [URDF file](https://pastebin.com/uJnnerRH). As you can see I tried to stack two continuous joints after each other. Unfortunately, when I try to manipulate them in Rviz I can only see changes in the second joint (base_to_caster2).
Does anybody know how to implement revolute joints with more than one degree of freedom properly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261919/joint-with-three-degrees-of-freedom-urdf/) by [Kaonashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30379/kaonashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve my problem with a workaround by setting mu1, mu2 to zero and slip1, slip2 to one for the caster. This means, that there will be no friction between the ground and the caster.
Anyway, I am still interested in my initial question. How do I implement a joint with two rotational degrees of freedom? I think this will be relevant for me in the future, since I want to experiment as well with a robotic arm in ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Kaonashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30379/kaonashi/) with karma: 38 on 2017-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tnajjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/36992/tnajjar/) on 2022-02-19**:
5 years later I'm still interested in this if someone has an answer